# C# Class Inheritance Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, inheritance, methods

So I am not using a masterpage due to the small size of the project and the general intention of keeping things lean. As such I'd like to include a class on a simple cs file and use it on the same page.

```
// <copyright file="anon.cs" company="Anonymous">
//     ;
// </copyright>

namespace cheese.pies.org
{
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

/// <summary>
///   Class to process CAS authentication.
///   Based on solutions from CASE and Yale.
/// </summary>
public class CasLogin
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Address of university cas host
    /// </summary>
    private const string CasHost = "notimportant";

    /// <summary>
    ///   Get the logged-in user's id or redirect them to login.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// DirectoryID of logged in user
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetId()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The rest is fairly unimportant. I believe this to be a basic syntax error.

Here is the file test.aspx, which uses a page include.

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="CasLogin" CodeFile="anon.cs" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String directoryId = CasLogin.GetId();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(directoryId, false);
}
</script>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
```

I'm fairly new at this sort of thing and I'd like to know what's going wrong and what the proper syntax is. Thanks!

Comment: Can you fully qualify the type name and then try again? eg `cheese.pies.org.CasLogin.GetId` - It sounds like might simply need a import directive.

Comment: your error is trying to speak to you :)

Comment: If you're working for Anonymous one would think you'd be able to solve this yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message tells you the problem. Change the class to this:

```
public class CasLogin : Page
```

Answer (score 4):

Just update the class to derive from page:

```
public class CasLogin : Page
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly what is wrong:

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, **and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).**

Does `public class CasLogin {}` Extend `Page` or `UserControl` ?